# How to make bundler respect Ruby version for sub-dependencies?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bundle, bundler

Ruby version: 1.9.3

Gemfile:

```
   ruby '1.9.3'
   source 'http://rubygems.org'
   gem 'site_prism', '2.6'
```

Running "bundle install" fails with:

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.2.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
 site_prism was resolved to 2.6, which depends on
  capybara was resolved to 2.15.4, which depends on
   xpath was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
    nokogiri
```

nokogiri 1.8.1 is incompatible with Ruby 1.9.3.

**Why does bundle try to install a gem that isn't compatible with my current Ruby version?**

Things I've tried:

- Different bundler version (1.12.5, 1.15.4, 1.16.0)
- Specify "ruby '1.9.3' in Gemfile"

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to specify a much older version of nokogiri to get this to work. You may have to specify older versions of capybara or xpath as well. Try putting in your Gemfile

`gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.8'`

and work from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why, though? Shouldn't specifying my ruby version automatically determine which sub-dependency version I need?